# Quadratic reciprocity for some fields

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

I am reading recently about quadratic reciprocity, and I am interested in studying how to calculate quadratic reciprocity for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-a})$ as suggested by my tutor. Do you know any comprehensive source that explain the concept  clearly? When I google it it seems does not give any relevant outcomes.

Comment: The usual quadratic reciprocity is obtained from expressing $\pm \sqrt{d}$ as a [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) to make obvious the Frobenius element. Now quadratic reciprocity for $K$ can be a different thing : showing the splitting of primes in quadratic extensions of $K$ is given by Hecke characters of $K$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you suggest a source. I really don't understand what you are saying. @reuns

Comment: What do you not understand ? Search for 'quadratic reciprocity gauss sum'